# Agrupar elementos dentro de una lista

Tags: python, dataframe

Buenas tengo una lista de 800 datos donde el índice es una fecha y los tengo que agrupar cada X meses y mirar si en esos X meses se cumple una condición y después de agruparlos crear una nueva lista con los datos agrupados

Ejemplo

Tengo 100 datos de fechas en una lista y todas tienen una respuesta binaria en otra columna.  los tengo que agrupar de a 5 (D1= enero a mayo del 2000) y si en esos 5 datos hay un  “1”, D1 =1 y si no igual a “0”

El problema es cómo rebanar esa lista

Muchas gracias

en excel lo hice de esta forma
[image: Ejemplo excel]

obviamente el valor de 1965 es cero

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas algo de código referente a los que quieres, usualmente las imágenes no representan nada, toda vez, para mejor entendimiento de que es lo quieres.  Por favor, leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo algunas cosas que no veo del todo claras en la pregunta, yo lo haría así con Python:

En primer lugar la estructura original con los datos la he creado en una lista de `dict`'s, se asume ya cargada en el programa de alguna manera:

```
datos = [
    {"fecha": "2019-01", "B": 0.1, "C": 1},
    {"fecha": "2019-02", "B": 1.1, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-03", "B": 2.1, "C": 1},
    {"fecha": "2019-04", "B": 1.1, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-05", "B": 0.31, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-06", "B": 0.321, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-07", "B": 0.4, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-08", "B": 0.1, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-09", "B": 0.2, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-10", "B": 1.4, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-11", "B": 1.5, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2019-12", "B": 0.1, "C": 1},
    {"fecha": "2020-01", "B": 0.2, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2020-02", "B": 1.4, "C": 0},
    {"fecha": "2020-03", "B": 1.5, "C": 0},
]
```

La siguiente asunción es que sólo vamos a procesar grupos de 5 elementos completos:

```
total_grupos = len(datos) // 5
```

Por último, recorremos la lista procesando segmentos de 5 elementos de la lista original, para cada uno de los cuales los convierto en una lista de binarios de la columna "C" y de esa lista genero un 0 o 1 en función de la regla definida en la pregunta. Adicionalmente al dato `0/1` añado un campo adicional con la primera fecha del grupo de fechas que se procesan, para depurar o verificar que se calcula OK:

```
agrupaciones = [{"fecha1": datos[i*5]['fecha'], "D": next(filter(lambda c: c == 1, map(lambda o: o['C'], datos[i*5:(i+1)*5])), 0)} for i in range(total_grupos) ]
```

El resultado de lo anterior sería algo como:

```
>>> agrupaciones
[{'fecha1': '2019-01', 'D': 1}, {'fecha1': '2019-06', 'D': 0}, {'fecha1': '2019-11', 'D': 1}]
```